# Early 2000's fairy fantasy book series with mountain range on cover

Tags: story-identification, fairy

I read a book series a couple years ago that I am trying to find. The first book had a mountain range on the cover and I believe the title had "Gaia" in it. It was about a young girl with green eyes and red hair who turns out to be the leader of the fairies in this other realm. 
The second or third book cover depicted a war scene between the two different types of fairies. If I remember right, she had some sort of powers but didn't know about them and I believe her parents had died in a car crash when she was younger. 
If anyone has Any idea what this could be, that would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you read it?  What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: Gaia - https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25086524-gaia. Notably her parents die in a car crash. There's a war, but between angels, not fairies.

Comment: Lead character is called Gaia, All of her friends are killed in a car crash thjat she survives. She becomes embroiled in a war between angel and faeries; https://www.amazon.co.uk/Shattering-Halos-Book-1-ebook/dp/B00ILXYKTK